# Codeigniter preform query like: where md5(column) = $hash

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

He i'm moving a project to a codeigniter project. In this project I put a `md5(id)` in my `url` like

```
http://example.com?hash=424bbf597a23a198b69b1b8cc4674260
```

I get the hash from the url and search in my database which client is requested like:

```
$hash = $_GET['hash'];

SELECT * FROM sites WHERE md5(id) = $hash
```

is something like this possible in codeigniter?

Comment: Are you storing `hash` value within `id` then remove that `md5` part from the query and you'll get your answer

Comment: You NEED to read the documents from codeigniter . See [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: @Uchiha i have removed md5 part in query, but still now am not getting answer my query is `SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `id` = 'c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:
$this->db->where("md5(id) = $hash", '', false);
$query = $this->db->get('sites');
$result = $query->result();